Are spaces that can be embedded in a topological W-group first countable?
This question is linked to Are W-spaces with countable pseudocharacter first countable?.
Here I state the following definition:
A topological space $X$ is embeddable in a topological W-group if it is homeomorphic to a subspace of a W-space that has a group topology (see also: W-space and has a group topology).
I am thinking about more possible counterexamples to answer to my previous question (cited at the beginning), and I got interested in knowing whether the Peng-Wu Group or the Weak topology on separable Hilbert space are W-spaces or not.
After this, I noticed that there are no examples of spaces that are embeddable in a topological W-group, but that aren't first countable. So, additionally, I was wondering if anyone knows an example of such, or if embeddable in a topological W-group implies first countable.
